# C# MAF AddInStore.FindAddIns load addin with higher version

Tags: c#, maf

Is it possible to load addin with higher version ?

[1] XYZ_A.dll

[AddIn("XYZ",Version="1.0.0.0") ]
 public class XYZPlugin : MsPluginView

[2] XYZ_B.dll

[AddIn("XYZ",Version="1.0.2.0") ]
 public class XYZPlugin : MsPluginView

Initially we have deployed XYZ_A.dll at cliend end.

Now we can only allowed to copy XYZ_B.dll at client end so that on next plugin discovery it should take latest version.

I have tried it but it is not taking latest version.

Need help.

Comment: Overwrite the original file?

Comment: Plugin is running and not allowed to overwrite. I have tried it.

Comment: Did you regenerate the pipeline after placing the new dll in the addin folder?